# Give users specific options in a single line text field - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: validation

I have a list with a single line text field - [title]. Due to users being difficult, I now need to tighten this field down and only allow them to enter certain options. I was trying to do this via column validation but am running into syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is allow certain options mean, if it is fixed, hide the title column and create a new choice field. If you have dynamic or dependent options that vary with something else, then attach an event receiver using C# and perform a validation on itemadding event.

Also if you use SharePoint Designer, there will be are ways to edit the default form to add validations.

Comment: Yes - it is a fixed list of options. Thank you for your answer.